# Run a CronJob every 15 minutes starting from 11.30 PM to 01.30 AM

Tags: cron

Whats the expression to run a CronJob every 15 minutes starting from 11.30 PM to 01.30 AM

(11.30, 11.45, 00.00, 00.15, 00.30, 00.45, 1.00, 1.15, 1.30)

Do I have to break this in two or can I do it with only one?

This was the closest I got:

```
15/15,30,45 23,0,1 * * *

 next at 2018-11-08 23:15:00
 then at 2018-11-08 23:30:00
 then at 2018-11-08 23:45:00
 then at 2018-11-09 00:15:00
 then at 2018-11-09 00:30:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this …

```
*/15 * * * * ts=$(date "+%H%M") ; test $ts -gt 1130 -a $ts -lt 2359 -o $ts -gt 0000 -a $ts -lt 0130 && /path/to/command
```

… this is untested or course.  The idea is every 15 minutes you check what time it is and if it is within the ranges defined in the conditions, you execute your command.  Also it wouldn't hurt to have two cron entries.  Which is probably simpler.